# Forcing "server" comments on Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, razor, comments

On Visual Studio 2022, I am programming a website in asp.net core 8 C#.

Trying to comment some code via the button in the top bar, I get a "javascript" style comment if I am in javascript into a CSHTML. Can Visual Studio be told to always make razor-style "server" comments?

It would be helpful to reduce the plain text comments in the code once you compile and release the site.

Comment: which button you are clicking? I always press `Ctrl + K + C` to comment the line and `Ctrl + K + U` to uncomment the line. If the current file is `.cs`, then the selected line will be added `//`, if the current file is `.cshtml`, the selected line will be surrounded with `@*  xxxx   *@` Not very sure what you want to achieve...

Answer (score 0):

I trust I can understand your requirement.

[image]

In js part, if we use the default comment way, it will give us `//content` which makes you worried about having too much `plain text comments in the code` , so that you want to have `@* content *@` as the default comment for cshtml file.

However, I didn't find such settings in my VS 2022 community version. So that I'm afraid we couldn't set it directly.

[image]

Comment: custom keyboard shortcuts can't  help us create a new shortcut to do custom action: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/identifying-and-customizing-keyboard-shortcuts-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2022